# how to create a customized java script alerts and pass it an object property inside my asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following Ajax.actionlink to perform a deletion:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer", 
        new { id = answer.AnswersID }, 
          new AjaxOptions 
          { 
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?", 
              HttpMethod = "Post", 
              UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(), 
              OnSuccess = "removePartial2", 
          })
```

and the following removePartial2 java script that will be called Onsuccess:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function removePartial2() { 
        alert('Deletion was successful');  
        $(this).remove(); 
} 
</script>
```

currently both the `Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",` & the `alert('Deletion was successful');` alerts are being displayed with a non-user friendly alerts that looks like these are error messages and not confirmation messages so i have the following two questions:

1. how can i modify the look and feel (colors & text) and provide customized java scripts alerts.
2. how i pass the answer.Description for the object that will be deleted to be displayed as part of the alert message?

**Edited:-**
i tried the Bootsrap alerts as they look cool, but when i navigate to the intended view i got the following error `"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'"` on the `"$('body').on('click.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)"` inside the bootstrap-alert.js file. so what might cause the problem?

Comment: for 1 there are a number of jQuery plugins that replace the default alert/confirm entirely. Google around!

Comment: You can't change alert and confirm popups, as they are provided by the browser. Use custom ones instead (jQueryUI, or others)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the alert dialog, you could use a modal or just add a little notification element to your page. I'd recommend using something like the [Bootsrap alerts](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#alerts); they look great and are easy to implement.

Comment: i tried the Bootsrap alerts as they look cool, but when i navigate to the intended view i got the following error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'" on the "$('body').on('click.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)" inside the bootstrap-alert.js file. so what might cause the problem?

Comment: @johnG: Looks like you're missing the jQuery dependency.

Comment: no i have included these scripts in the _layout view:- <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>